# Entity Framework equivalent of NHibernate "subselect fetching"

Tags: entity-framework

NHibernate has a fetching strategy called "Subselect Fetching" which is detailed here: https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/performance.html

TLDR: the idea is when we have an entity like this:

```
class Foo
{
    ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

rather than doing a join, we can retrieve both the Foos and the Bars in separate queries (with the results stitched together by NHibernate). In pseudo code:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE Name = 'John'

SELECT * FROM Bar WHERE FooId IN (:idFromFirstQuery)
```

This is useful in the case that Foo is wide and joining to Bar would retrieve a large amount of data.

Is there an equivalent in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, this can be achieved like this:

```
var foos = DbContext.Set<Foo>().Where(x => x.Name == 'John').ToList();

var fooIds = foos.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();

var bars = DbContext.Set<Bar>().Where(x => foos.Contains(x.FooId)).ToList();
```

The **bars** variable is then just thrown away (and Resharper will get annoyed), however by virtue of this all occurring within the same DbContext, the Foos will now have their Bar collections populated.